# Input type="number" with pattern="[0-9]*" allows letters in firefox

Tags: html

The question is in the topic's title. Input `type="number"` with `pattern="[0-9]*"` works fine in Chrome, but allows letters in Firefox. Is there any way to fix it without using jQuery or JS?

```css
.small-input {
    -moz-appearance: textfield;
}
.small-input::-webkit-inner-spin-button {
    display: none;
}

.small-input::-webkit-outer-spin-button,
.small-input::-webkit-inner-spin-button {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<input class="small-input" pattern="[0-9]*" value="" type="number">
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Seems that Firefox doesn't restrict you from entering alphabetic characters into a number input, however it still will validate the input upon submitting your form as seen below. Note that both `e` and `E` are valid in numeric inputs.

Also, according to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/number),

> `<input type="number">` elements do not support use of the pattern
>   attribute for making entered values conform to a specific regex
>   pattern. The rationale for this is that number inputs can't contain
>   anything except numbers, and you can constrain the minimum and maximum
>   number of valid digits using the min and max attributes

So no need to use it.

Selecting a numeric input really does two things. First on mobile devices is should bring up a numeric keypad instead of a normal keyboard to enter input, second it should only allow numbers as valid input. So if you want to prevent a user from entering text into one, you'll need JavaScript.

You'll see by the example below that when you try and submit the form, if the input isn't numeric it will prompt you to correct it, and the pattern attribute is unnecesary:

```css
.small-input {
  -moz-appearance: textfield;
}
.small-input::-webkit-inner-spin-button {
  display: none;
}
.small-input::-webkit-outer-spin-button,
.small-input::-webkit-inner-spin-button {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <input class="small-input" value="" type="number">
  <button>Button</button>
</form>
```

Comment: This does not prevent text input in firefox, at least not in 2021

Comment: and not in 2023 as well.

Comment: not in 2024 as well

Answer (score 18):

You could use `Regex` to completely prevent the user from entering in any letters into the `input` field.

So on your input element I would add the following event listener: `onkeypress="preventNonNumericalInput(event)"`

```
<input class="small-input " pattern="[0-9]*" value="" type="number" onkeypress="preventNonNumericalInput(event)">
```

And then in your JavaScript file you'd create the following function:

```
function preventNonNumericalInput(e) {
  e = e || window.event;
  var charCode = (typeof e.which == "undefined") ? e.keyCode : e.which;
  var charStr = String.fromCharCode(charCode);

  if (!charStr.match(/^[0-9]+$/))
    e.preventDefault();
}
```

I've tested this and it should prevent any non numerical input and any special characters eg **@#./?** etc...

Comment: This does not considers -, . and any other key.

Comment: Did you test this? Firefox doesn't do anything with this unless the field is also "required"

Comment: this works perfectly, the only thing i would change is to use the event.key because the other ones are deprecated. Like so:
!/^\d*$/.test(event.key)

Answer (score 4):

> elements **do not support use of the pattern attribute for making entered values conform to a specific regex
>   pattern**. The rationale for this is that number inputs can't contain
>   anything except numbers, and you can constrain the minimum and maximum
>   number of valid digits using the min and max attributes, as explained
>   above.

Link: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/number

You should use Javascript instead, following [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/469357/html-text-input-allows-only-numeric-input?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa).

Comment: input `type="number">` allows `e` symbol, so I added pattern to avoid that.

Comment: Yes I know because e as I suppose you know is a number. The only option is to use JS

Answer (score 2):

For anyone interested in syntax which is using non-deprecated properties (which, keyCode):

```
const handleAllowNumbers = (e) => {
  if (e.target.type === "number" && !e.key.match(/^[0-9]+$/)) {
    e.preventDefault();
  }
};
```

Comment: Just a warning: this also deactivates functional keys (STRG+A, arrow keys etc)

Answer (score -1):

It will work with country code "[0-9]+$" (regex format).

Note: Blank space are allowed with above regex code.

Without blank space-

It will work with country code "^[-+()]*[0-9][-+()0-9]*$".

Note: Blank space are not allowed with above regex code.

Answer (score -2):

Working for chrome, firefox & safari (latest browser version)

```
<input
  class="form-control"
  min="1"
  type="text"
  maxlength="1000000"
  @keypress="onlyNumber"
 >
```

and method

```
function onlyNumber ($event) {
    let keyCode = ($event.keyCode ? $event.keyCode : $event.which);
    if ((keyCode < 48 || keyCode > 57) && keyCode !== 190) { // 46 is dot
        $event.preventDefault();
    }
},
```