# How to show an alert in JavaScript based on specific user input

Tags: javascript, alert

I need an alert that says "enter a digit from 0 to 9 please" when typing a letter, a comma, minus, plus, bracket, question mark etc. (only numbers can be entered).

My alert is not working, I cannot connect it.
I am asking you for help.

The alert should be shown after trying to enter letters, commas etc. in the table, except for numbers

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>

<body>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    (function($) {
      $.fn.average = function() {

        var sum = 0;
        this.each(function() {
          sum += parseFloat($(this).val());
          //;
        });

        return sum / $(this).length;
      }

    })(jQuery);
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $(":reset")
    });


    $(document).ready(function() {
      $("#calc").click(function() {
        var s = $("input[type='number']").average();
        console.debug(s);
        $('#result').html(s);
      });
      $(".reset").on('click', function() {
        $("#result").html(" ");
      })
    });
  </script>

  <h1>Oblicz średnią:</h1>
  <form action="">
    <input onkeypress="if((event.keyCode < 48 || event.keyCode > 57) && (event.keyCode != 44))return false" type="number"><br>
    <input onkeypress="if((event.keyCode < 48 || event.keyCode > 57) && (event.keyCode != 44))return false" type="number"><br>
    <input onkeypress="if((event.keyCode < 48 || event.keyCode > 57) && (event.keyCode != 44))return false" type="number"><br>
    <div id="result" type="reset"></div><br>
    <input type="button" id="calc" value="Licz">
    <input type="reset" value="Reset" class="reset">
  </form>

  <script>
    function setTimeout(function() {}, 10);
    () {
      confirm("Press a button!");
    }
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Could you have it that you completely prevent any non numerical input, therefore, not needed to have the alert appear or is the alert essential?

Comment: I need an alert when I try to enter letters, commas, etc ...

Comment: Your inputs contain invalid formatting inline of the `onkeypress` events, there is additional quotes. Also you say `My alert is not working,` - I don't see any alert in your code. It can't work if it doesn't exist.

Comment: Idk how to connect this 
<script>
function myFunction() {
    alert(""enter a digit from 0 to 9 please!");
}
</script>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [Input type="number" with pattern="[0-9]*" allows letters in firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49923588/input-type-number-with-pattern-0-9-allows-letters-in-firefox/49924215#49924215) as a reference.

So with the help of `regex` you can prevent different input types. So on your `onkeypress` method use the following function:

```
<input onkeypress="preventNonNumericalInput(event)" type="number">
```

Then declare this function in your `js` file:

```
function preventNonNumericalInput(e) {
  e = e || window.event;
  var charCode = (typeof e.which == "undefined") ? e.keyCode : e.which;
  var charStr = String.fromCharCode(charCode);

  if (!charStr.match(/^[0-9]+$/)){
    alert("Enter a digit from 0 to 9 please")
    e.preventDefault();
  }
}
```

Comment: it works, thank you :3 
Is there also an option for the comma to work?

Comment: @Missyou update the `regex` in the if statement to the following to allow commas: /^[0-9,\b]+$/